# Compc "could not find a JVM"

Tags: java, path, jvm, compc

When I try to use `compc` to build a .swc, I get `Error: could not find a JVM`.

I found [this](http://renaun.com/blog/2006/03/compc-error-could-not-find-a-jvm/)  site, and then commented out the java.home line. That didn't help.

I'm trying to build a .swc out of [this library](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient), so I can actually use it. I also have FlashBuilder, if I can build or add this library to my project through that instead, that would be nice.

**EDIT**: Setting `JAVA_HOME` to the `jre` or `jdk` directories gives me variations of a different error `Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`

**EDIT 2**: After wrapping `JAVA_HOME` in strings,  I get the error I had before I downloaded the JDK:

```
Error: could not find JRE
Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.
```

I can type`%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version` and see `java version "1.7.0_45`, however.

Replacing `JAVA_HOME` with the path to the `JRE`  doesn't help.

**EDIT 3** After installing and setting `JAVA_HOME` to the 32-bit sdk, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Jim\Downloads\as3httpclient-master\as3httpclient-master\build-swc.xml(14): Error: unable to open 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks/libs/player/9/playerglobal.swc'

</external-library-path>
```

I noticed that the file path uses switches from using backslashes to forward slashes, so I changed them back, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C:\Program Files\Java` is typically the directory into which the JDK is installed. Set the environmental variable to a specific `JDK`, for example

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"
```

Comment: In this case, he might need the JDK and not the JRE - based on the error message he describes

Comment: @AmirAfghani Setting JAVA_Home to be the jdk gives me `Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`

Comment: That was given as an example. What is the exact path where your JDK is installed?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`, which is what I set as JAVA_HOME`

Comment: what happens when you type %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version ?  If that doesn't work, you haven't set JAVA_HOME properly

Comment: I get `C:\Program is not recognized...`, so perhaps the space is messing it up

Comment: I wrapped my `JAVA_HOME` variable in quotes, and now I can get the java version, but I still can't run compc. I'll update my question...done

Comment: Are you running `compc` in the same DOS window where you set `JAVA_HOME`? I would set the variable in the `System Properties Environment` Windows dialog

Comment: I set all the variables with the Windows dialog, and I open a new `cmd` window after every change. I even restarted my computer after my last edit

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit JDK? Also [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd9.html) may help

Comment: I'm using a 64-bit JDK

Comment: The [config doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd9.html) says _You must use a 32-bit version of the JDK_

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem and my fix was to change the back slashes to forward slashes for the java.home setting in jvm.cfg.

So in "flexsdk/bin/jvm.config" change,

java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)Java\jre7

To,

java.home=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7

And now compc, etc, can find the JVM and work.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

The `JAVA_HOME` should point to the JRE/JDK you want to use as it is possible to store more than 1 jvm in `C:\Program Files\Java` .
If you are using Java 7 your `JAVA_PATH` should point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` for example.

Comment: I get `Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll` after doing that

Comment: check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123144/missing-server-jvm-java-jre7-bin-server-jvm-dll

Comment: That didn't help. I already have a folder called `server`, and I don't have a folder named `client`

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of Flex `mxmlc` and `compc` compilers: the can't use *x64* JDK, use *i586* (*IA32*) JDK versions. See more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064938/907576