# Java program files (x86) and program files 64 bit and 32 bit

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript

I'am trying to execute `mxmlc` (Flex application compiler) and I get this error:

```
Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

I've got `java` in my `program files (x86)` and the other `java` in my `program files`, I'am using windows 7 64 bit. After I've installed the 32 bit from java official site, I've still got there a 64 bit.

Can someone tell me how to replace it?

Comment: See the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955280/mxmlc-and-64bit-jre

It may help full to you.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click "Computer"
choose "Properties"
from the left choose "Advanced system settings"
be sure you are on "Advanced" tab
from the bottom press "Environment Variables"
From the second box "system variables" search for "Path" and double-click or select it and press edit
go to the end of the text "Variable value" and add ";" then the new url for example (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin)