# Flex compiler not working with 32 bit JVM(1.8.0_25)

Tags: java, apache-flex, jvm, 32-bit

I have read this answer but not worked for me. [MXMLC and 64bit JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955280/mxmlc-and-64bit-jre)

**. I have 32 bit JVM and I have set the java.home in the jvm.config

Flex version: [Open Source Flex SDK 4.1.0](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Download%20Flex%204/)

java version "1.8.0_25".

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18).

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing).

System: windows 10 x64(eval build 9841)

Error is

**Error loading: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_25\bin\client\jvm.dll**

Is there a compatible java version for Flex  4.0.1?

**Edit: Version 4.13.0 working though.**

Comment: I added a new answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955280/mxmlc-and-64bit-jre/29582907#29582907 which should help you: Use batch files instead of the exe files.

Answer (score 1):

This error suggests your JDK is not installed correctly.  Try uninstalling it and re-installing it.

BTW [Windows 10 is not supported for the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html), so it may be that you can't install for this eval version of the OS.

You could also try the 64-bit version of the JDK to see if you have more luck with that.

This error has nothing to do with Flex.

Comment: So far any of my java applications(native calls tested too) didn't fail on JDK 8 with windows 10, including netbeans.

Flex 4.1.0 is not support on 64-bit JDK.